# The native method is not called after switching to the new qt and Gradle

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

Call of native C++ functions from Java stopped working.

With Qt5.10/gradle:2.3.3/ndk-r16b/jdk-1.7.0-55 worked fine:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mypackage;
...
public class MainActivity extends QtActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        s_instance = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        registerNatives();
        ...
    }

    private native void registerNatives();
}
```

**somecppfile.cpp**

```
#include <QAndroidJniObject>
#include <QAndroidJniEnvironment>
#include <jni.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_mypackage_MainActivity_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jobject)
{
   ... // 
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

After changing versions when running on Android error occurs.
Qt5.12/gradle:3.2.0/ndk-18.1.5063045/jdk-1.8.0-192

```
E zygote  : No implementation found for void com.mypackage.MainActivity.registerNatives() (tried Java_com_mypackage_MainActivity_registerNatives and Java_com_mypackage_MainActivity_registerNatives__)
D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mypackage, PID: 26735
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.mypackage.MainActivity.registerNatives() (tried Java_com_mypackage_MainActivity_registerNatives and Java_com_mypackage_MainActivity_registerNatives__)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.mypackage.MainActivity.registerNatives(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
I Process : Sending signal. PID: 26735 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Are you calling `System.loadLibrary()` before method call?

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks. Strange, but before such a call was not required.

Answer (score 1):

thank you, Kunal Puri.

Added line: `System.loadLibrary("LibraryName")` befor call registerNatives:

```
package com.mypackage;
...
public class MainActivity extends QtActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        s_instance = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        System.loadLibrary("LibraryName"); // without lib
        registerNatives();
        ...
    }

    private native void registerNatives();
}
```